# Calling WaitForMultipleObjects on multiple mutexes with timeout with C++

Tags: c++, winapi, synchronization, mutex

If I call [WaitForMultipleObjects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687025%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on multiple mutexes like so:

```
HANDLE hMutexes[5] = {...};   //All mutexes
DWORD dwRet = WaitForMultipleObjects(5, hMutexes, TRUE, 5 * 1000);
```

And `dwRet` is returned as `WAIT_TIMEOUT`, what state will be mutexes in the `hMutexes` array? Or, in other words shall I call `ReleaseMutex` on any of them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The docs for the `WaitForMultipleObjects` function state that:

> When bWaitAll is TRUE, ... the function does not modify the states of the specified 
>   objects until the states of all objects have been set to signaled. For example, a
>   mutex can be signaled, but the thread does not get ownership until the states of the
>   other objects are also set to signaled.

Therefore you do not need to worry about this situation. If `WaitForMultipleObjects` returns `WAIT_TIMEOUT` you do not own any of the mutexes. If it returns `WAIT_OBJECT_0` you own all of them.

Answer (score 0):

If you get a `WAIT_TIMEOUT` it means that no mutex was signalled, so you shouldn't call `ReleaseMutex` in any of them.